# Redefine ID with ampersand

Tags: php, jquery

Working with Sly's scrolling codes (http://darsa.in/sly/).

Having multiple Sly carousels on a page, I need to fix the ID of the frame

I generate them with **'#=basic-XXX'**, where XXX is the record of the album.

the standard code is this:

```
var $frame  = $('#basic');
var $slidee = $frame.children('ul').eq(0);
var $wrap   = $frame.parent();
```

I try to read the ID, including the attached record number from the database.

```
var $frame  = $("[id^=basic-]"); // start with...

// trying these two lines, but they FAIL
var num = $frame.slice(7); 
var $frame  = $("#basic-"+num);

//from here $frame should be redefined as #basic-THENUMBER

var $slidee = $frame.children('ul').eq(0);
var $wrap   = $frame.parent();
```

Any idea how I can update var $frame with the ID so it works for the rest of the script?

Comment: Is PHP related?

Comment: In a way, yes; it is used in an entirely php scripted site.

Comment: It is not related to the script/question you are asking though, right?

Comment: You're right. Thanks for keeping me focussed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("[id^=basic-]")` will return the elements that match the selector and you can then use `.attr('id')` to get the first element's id value. If there is only one element with an id starting with `basic-` then this will work:

```
$frame = $("[id^=basic-]").attr('id');
```

Note that when you use `String.slice`, character positions start at 0, so I think you probably want:

```
var num = $frame.slice(6);
```

See this demo:

```js
var $frame = $("[id^=basic-]").attr('id');
console.log($frame);
var num = $frame.slice(6); 
console.log(num);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span id="basic-355">hello world!</span>
</div>
```

If you have multiple elements that have matching id's you will need to iterate them using `.each` or similar:

```js
var $frames = $("[id^=basic-]");
$frames.each(function () {
    let id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
    let num = id.slice(6); 
    console.log(num);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<span id="basic-355">hello world!</span>
<span id="basic-562">hello world!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("[id^=basic-]")[0]` return dom element and you can't use `.attr('id')` after it

Comment: Thank you so much @Nick! Your solution works even better than what I eventually came up with. I also used the .each on it, like this: $("[id^=basic-]").each(function() {
var num = this.id.slice(6); $frame = $("#basic-"+num);....etc. Will be using yours though! Many thanks!